# How to display 5 more rows of a table on the click on a button using jQuery

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I pre-load a table with all of its rows. However, I only want to show only the top 10 rows that are within the `<tbody>` tag and now every `<tr>` in the table.

So here is what I have done so far:

```
var trs =  $("#internalActivities > table > tbody > tr");
trs.hide();
trs.slice(0, 9).show(); 

$("#seeMoreRecords").click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#internalActivities tr:hidden").slice(0, 10).show();          
});

$("#seeLessRecords").click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#internalActivities tr").slice(9, 19).hide();          
});
```

The issue with the code above is that:

1. It does look for the `<tr>` only with the the `<tbody>` tag.
2. The see less button need to remove 10 rows from the bottom up and not all of them.
3. I need to hide the button `seeMoreRecords` if all of them are displayed.
4. If the minimum row is displayed then hide the `seeLessRecords` button.

Final look my script will display 10 rows by defaults and if the user click see more then you see 10 more. So it is an increment of 10 at a time and once you hit max then hide the see more button. See less is visible only if there are more than 10 rows displayed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. You can use the selector `$("#internalActivities tr")` which will select all `<tr>`'s, regardless  of a `<tbody>` or not
2. You need to save the current displayed index in a separate variable, or calculate the current index based on how many elements are selected (use the `.length` property)
3. Check the current count of elements displayed and show/hide the corresponding buttons.

### Example

#### HTML

```html
<table id="internalActivities">

</table>
<input type="button" id="seeMoreRecords" value="More">
<input type="button" id="seeLessRecords" value="Less">
```

#### Javascript

```js
for (var i=0;i<21;i++) {
    $('#internalActivities').append('<tr><td>my data</td></tr>');
}

var trs = $("#internalActivities tr");
var btnMore = $("#seeMoreRecords");
var btnLess = $("#seeLessRecords");
var trsLength = trs.length;
var currentIndex = 10;

trs.hide();
trs.slice(0, 10).show(); 
checkButton();

btnMore.click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#internalActivities tr").slice(currentIndex, currentIndex + 10).show();
    currentIndex += 10;
    checkButton();
});

btnLess.click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#internalActivities tr").slice(currentIndex - 10, currentIndex).hide();          
    currentIndex -= 10;
    checkButton();
});

function checkButton() {
    var currentLength = $("#internalActivities tr:visible").length;

    if (currentLength >= trsLength) {
        btnMore.hide();            
    } else {
        btnMore.show();   
    }

    if (trsLength > 10 && currentLength > 10) {
        btnLess.show();
    } else {
        btnLess.hide();
    }

}
```

I created a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UgBcn/1/) to see this in action.

Comment: This code appends rows to a table. I already have the rows but i want to show/hide them. I don't create any row

Comment: The generation of the rows is only for testing. You can completely remove the for-loop at the beginning.

Comment: I see. I was looking at the testing code and not the code you posted here. I tried your code but there are issues. the seeLEssRecords button does not hide. Also I don't see more that 10 records even thought there should be more that 10 records.

Comment: Mhm - sorry, I don't quite understand what's not working for you. Did you try the fiddle? Works as described here. What jQuery Version are you using? I updated the code above and in the fiddle a bit to be more inline with your original code and removed an un-needed check.

Comment: Now it is working. After your last update it is good. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

1) If you need the tr tags not only with the tbody tag then rewrite your jquery select to

```
$("#internalActivities > table tr");
```

2) You can get the number of rows and use that count in the slice

```
var $records = $("#internalActivities tr");
$records.slice($records.length - 10, $records.length).hide();
```

3) Check the count of hidden rows in the seeMoreRecords click event handler

```
if ($("#internalActivities tr:hidden").length === 0) {
    $("#seeMoreRecords").hide();
}
```

4) Check the count of shown rows

```
if ($("#internalActivities tr").not(":hidden").length <= 10) {
    $("#seeLessRecords").hide();
}
```

Comment: I actualy want to show/hide only the tr's that with in the tbody and not all of them.

Comment: In that case issue 1) is not an issue and your selector is correct.