# How to do show/hide of table rows multiple times per page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm fairly new to programming and JS so I would like some pointers in terms of how I would go about this. I want to use that code for multiple instance of toggle per page.

**I want by default table only shows 3 rows and when some click on view more it shows the rest of the rows and it should be toggle on click**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // toggle rows
    $( ".viewSection a" ).click(function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        var $nextUl = $self.parent().next();
        $(this).parent().next().slideToggle("fast");
    });
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="tabWrapper">
        <div class="tabContainer">
            <div class="tabContent" style="display: none;">
                <div class="childTable">
                    <table class="tableSeconday">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="2">TOTAL BACKLOG: 20</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lotus Greens Enviro City</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lotus Greens Enviro City</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <!--/tableSeconday-->
                </div>
                <!--/childTable-->
            </div>
            <!--/tabContent-->
            <div class="tabContent" style="display: block;">
                <div class="childTable">
                    <table class="tableSeconday">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="2">TOTAL BACKLOG: 30</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Gaursons Yamuna City Plots</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Gaursons Yamuna City Plots</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Gaursons Yamuna City Plots</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Gaursons Yamuna City Plots</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Gaursons Yamuna City Plots</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Gaursons Yamuna City Plots</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Gaursons Yamuna City Plots</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Gaursons Yamuna City Plots</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Gaursons Yamuna City Plots</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <!--/tableSeconday-->
                </div>
                <!--/childTable-->
            </div>
            <!--/tabContent-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="viewSection">   <a href="#">view more</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s9L128g9/

I don't want to have to work with manually adding separate IDs to the JS to activate the toggle. All I want to do is have multiple toggle areas on the same page, and use a class in the JS to work them all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display 5 more rows of a table on the click on a button using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254379/how-to-display-5-more-rows-of-a-table-on-the-click-on-a-button-using-jquery)

Comment: Why do you have two tables? Why is one hidden?

Comment: I want jquery solution not javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [DOM Traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) is the way forwards. It's the only way to work on children of an element selected by class, where the element may be present multiple times on a page (AFAIK).

Small HTML change to put the 'show more/less' link in to the parent table div... JS is:

```
$('.tableSeconday').each(function () {
    $(this).find('tr:gt(3)').hide();
});

$(".viewSection a").click(function () {
    var $table = $(this).parent().prevAll('div').find('table');
    $table.find('tr:gt(3)').toggle();
    $(this).html($(this).html() == 'view more' ? 'view less' : 'view more');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/rnwr07ar/6/

Comment: Thanks @Dave Salomon..you actually did want i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
// get all tr from second table with class="tableSeconday:eq"
var rows = $(".tableSeconday:eq(1) tr");
// slice after 4th row as first row include header part and hide them all
$(rows).slice(4,rows.length).each(function(index, element) {
       $(this).hide();
});
// toggle rows
    $( ".viewSection a" ).click(function() {
    // show all tr from table
    $(".tableSeconday:eq(1) tr").show();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/s9L128g9/18/)**

**EDIT** - to work same for multiple `table` with `class="tableSeconday"` and toggle show / hide rows, use below query :

```
var showingLess = false;

var showLess = function(){
  $(".tableSeconday").each(function(){
    var rows = $(this).find("tr");
    $(rows).slice(4,rows.length).each(function(index, element) {
       $(this).hide();
    });
  });

  showingLess = true;
}

// call showLess() for first time
showLess();

// toggle rows
$( ".viewSection a" ).click(function() {
    if(showingLess)
    {
      $(".tableSeconday tr").show();
        showingLess = false;
    }
    else
    {
       showLess(); 
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/s9L128g9/24/)**

Comment: This doesn't work with multiple tables. You'll probably need to use traversal methods.

Comment: @DaveSalomon, I added script for multiple table also. Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: thanks @Bhushan... what tweaks need to do if i want to toggle on view more. i mean when some one again click on view more it should go to its default state. One more thing view more toggle should work on seprately two table here when i click on view more it expands the both table.

Comment: Please check EDIT answer, I have updated to toggle rows and demo link also updated

Comment: @Bhushan....I want that toggle should work on two or more tables here when i click on view more its expanding the both tables. i mean that tables are appearing multiple times on different sections each have seprate view more link..ex http://jsfiddle.net/rnwr07ar/4/ here toggle is not working for second section

Comment: @Praveen, I have already added demo link for multiple table just after second script (see there are two demo links in my answer).. see this http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/s9L128g9/24/

Answer (score 0):

Building on the previous answer (nice work btw) this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rnwr07ar/2/) version will toggle the rows visibility as well as change the text to "view more/less".

```
// toggle rows
$( ".viewSection a" ).click(function() {
        $(rows).slice(4,rows.length).each(function(index, element) {
            if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
               $(this).hide();
               $("#showRows").html("view more");
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                $("#showRows").html("view less");
            }
        });
});
```

Bhushan did the heavy lifting here but i don't have enough rep to add this as a comment sorry