# How To Add A "Show More" Button To ForEach Loop?

Tags: php, json, api, loops, for-loop

Hi I am looking to add a Show More / Load More button to this For Each loop.
I am getting data from an API through JSON and displaying it in 3 columns.
I would like to limit it to say 3 rows of three, then perhaps use another row with only 1 td with a button centred with a GET parameter adding more to a Limit variable?

Here is my code how would be the best way to do this? Many thanks

```
$output = json_decode($output);
curl_close($ch);
$i = 0;
echo '<table border="0" align="center" padding-top="10px" padding-right="10px" padding-left="10px" padding-bottom="10px" style="width: 100% ">';
echo '<tr >';

foreach($output as $template) {
    echo '<td align="center"><br /><br /><b>' . '<font color="#0083C1" size="5" face="sans-serif">'.$template->template_name .'</font></b><br />';
    echo '<ul class="img-list"><li><a href="'.$template->preview_url.'" target="_blank"><img src="'. $template->thumbnail_url.'" height="250" width="370">'.'<span class="text-content"><b>'.'Preview Website'.'</b></span>'.'</a></li></ul>';
    echo '<form method="GET" value="/websites/choose-your-website.php">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="template_id" value="' . $template->template_id . '">';
    echo '<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email and Click Below" required" align="center" style="width: 250px">'.'<br />';
    echo '<button type="submit" align="center" class="button">Choose Site</button><br />';
    echo '</form></td>';        
    $i++;
    if($i == 3) {
        echo '</tr>'.'<tr>';
        $i = 0;
    }
}

echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

The file is in PHP with JSON data pulling information from an API displaying in a PHP table

Comment: you can do it with js  check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254379/how-to-display-5-more-rows-of-a-table-on-the-click-on-a-button-using-jquery